# `git add -p` doesn't work with Ctrl+h

Tags: git, macos, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

For those of you who don't know, by default on OSX, `ctrl + h` works the same as backspace.

For some reason, while running `git add -p`, if I type the wrong key, `ctrl+h` does not backspace, but instead ads `^H`.

Does anyone know why this is working differently than expected?

Does anyone know if there is anyway to get it working the way I would like?

Comment: Yes, using bash to run the `git-add` program, where I am seeing this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has little (not quite nothing) to do with Git specifically.

The problem is that the backspace *key* optionally sends either ASCII DEL or control-H, while control-H sends control-H.  Some programs—including most editors and popular shells—treat *both keys* as "delete previous character".

Others, as you have seen, do not.

There are different options here.  The one I use is to modify the backspace key to send control-H, and set up my `stty` settings to mark control-H as the "delete previous character" key.  You will find a checkbox labeled "Delete sends Control-H" under the Advanced tab in Terminal's Settings (changeable per profile).

For the `stty` settings, you just need to add the line `stty erase ^H` to your `.login` or `.profile` or some other file that is run when you create a new shell window; but be careful to set this only when the shell is an interactive shell, which you can tell by inspecting the shell's initial prompt (or some other, more shell-specific method, which will obviously depend on which shell you use).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to set the "`stty` settings to mark control-H as the \"delete previous character\" key"?

Comment: OK, well, against all good sense :-) I actually use `tcsh` so I just have this in `.login`: `stty erase ^H kill ^X status ^T eol2 undef` (note, the "control" characters here are actually spelled out as a hat/shift-six, followed by the character).  In fact this is inside an "if" clause with some slight variants for systems that lack `status` and/or `eol2` settings, but for MacOSX there is no issue here.  It is the `erase ^H` setting that sets control-H to be delete-previous-character.